# `.ok_or()` works but `.ok_or_else()` doesn't work even the type signature is the same

Tags: rust

You would find the following program has a compile error that looks difficult to fix:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;

// Custom error type
#[derive(Debug)]
struct APIError {
    message: String,
}

impl fmt::Display for APIError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.message)
    }
}

impl Error for APIError {}

// Function that demonstrates the issue
fn example_function() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let option: Option<String> = None; 

    option.ok_or_else(|| {
        Box::new(APIError {
            message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
        })
    })
}

fn main() {
    match example_function() {
        Ok(value) => println!("Success: {}", value),
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e),
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
19 |   fn example_function() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
   |                            ------------------------------ expected `Result<String, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>` because of return type
...
22 | /     option.ok_or_else(|| {
23 | |         Box::new(APIError {
24 | |             message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
25 | |         })
26 | |     })
   | |______^ expected `Result<String, Box<dyn Error>>`, found `Result<String, Box<APIError>>`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<_, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>`
              found enum `Result<_, Box<APIError>>`
```

However, changing it to `ok_or()` works:

```rust
    option.ok_or(
        Box::new(APIError {
            message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
        })
    )
```

I understand this is not the best practice of error handling in Rust, but this should be another question. It is likely that there do exist some nuances in the type inference.

I guess this could be related to some special type inference rules for closures or covariance/contravariance rules, but needs more effort to dive into it.

Update: I expect answers that explain the internal type inference rules. I know we have a lot of workarounds.

Comment: Try putting a question mark after `ok_or_else`.

Comment: You can just add `as _` after the `Box::new()`. That's enough for the compiler to get permission to convert `Box<ApiError>` to `Box<dyn ...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `ok_or`, the compiler notices that `Box::new` needs to create a value of type `Box<dyn Error>` and automatically converts the `Box<APIError>` for you. There aren't [too many things the compiler is allowed to convert](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) in this way, but converting a `Box` into a trait object is one of them.

Here's another example that won't compile, despite using `ok_or`:

```rust
let a = option.ok_or(Box::new(APIError {
    message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
}));
a
```

There's many ways to solve this. First is to add a return type to the closure.

```rust
option.ok_or_else(|| -> Box<dyn Error> {
    Box::new(APIError {
        message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
    })
})
```

This fixes the problem of coercion not reaching inside the closure.

You can also use [`into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into), which works because of [this impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#impl-From%3CE%3E-for-Box%3Cdyn+Error%3E).

```rust
option.ok_or_else(|| {
    Box::new(APIError {
        message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
    }).into()
})
```

Another way to use `into` is to use the try `?` operator.

```rust
Ok(option.ok_or_else(|| {
    Box::new(APIError {
        message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
    })
})?)
```

`?` calls `into` on the error type automatically.

You can also use `as` to explicitly cause the coercion.

```rust
option.ok_or_else(|| {
    Box::new(APIError {
        message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
    }) as Box<dyn Error>
})
```

Or you can use a let-binding to specify the type.

```rust
option.ok_or_else(|| {
    let e: Box<dyn Error> = Box::new(APIError {
        message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
    });
    e
})
```

Comment: Thanks @drewtato. I wonder if my understanding is correct: you have to put `Box::new(APIError{...})` into a context where it can be directly inferred to as `Box<dyn Error>` rather than `Box<APIError>`. Putting it into the closure, or saving it into a temp variable using `let`, both result in Box<APIError>.

Comment: Yes exactly, that plus the fact that `Option<Box<APIError>>` can't coerce to `Option<Box<dyn Error>>` at all. So it needs to be coerced while still a plain `Box<APIError>`.

Answer (score 1):

With the new [**let-else**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html) pattern, the function is not only clearer (no closures, no type conversions), but also the `.ok_or()` and `.ok_or_else()` constructs become obsolete:

```
fn example_function() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let option: Option<String> = None;
    let Some(ok) = option else {
        return Err(Box::new(APIError {
            message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
        }));
    };
    Ok(ok)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    option.ok_or_else(|| {
        Box::new(APIError {
            message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
        })
    })
```

You want:

```
    Ok(option.ok_or_else(|| {
        Box::new(APIError {
            message: "Custom error message".to_string(),
        })
    })?)
```

This obtains the APIError and then returns as the expected error type.

Output:

```
Error: Custom error message
```

Comment: Yes, but `Box<APIError>` should already subtype to `Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`. Why adding one layer of Ok works?

Comment: @zsf222 It's not the `Ok` layer that's making it work, it's the `?` operator.